# How do I clear only a few of the previous outputted cout lines in the console?

Tags: c++, cout

When I output a 3-string-component email message object in the console (sender's address, subject, email message), how do give the user the option to clear just those instead of the entire console?

```
    //MAIN MENU OPTION 1 SELECTED:
// print list of all messages to the console
void viewInbox()
{
    vector<Message> inbox{
        Message("jayleno@hotmail.com", "Knife you tonight", "Hey Sam, what kind of suit do you wanna be buried in?!"),
        Message("paypalservices@hotmail.com", "Urgent from paypal.com", "Dear paypal user, someone has hacked your account. Give us your password now so we change it!"),
    };
    cout << "You have " << inbox.size() << " new messages.\n";
    cout << "Index      Subject" << '\n';

    for (int i = 0; i < inbox.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Message " << i << ": " << inbox[i].getSubject() << '\n';
    }//end of for loop
    cout << "Please enter number of message you would like to view\n";
    int message_number;
    cin >> message_number;
    cout << "From: " << inbox[message_number].getAddress() << endl;
    cout << "Subject: " << inbox[message_number].getSubject() << endl;
    cout << inbox[message_number].getMessageText() << endl;
    cout << "To close this message and return to your inbox, press 1\n";
    //cin.clear(previous 4 cout lines above only);
}//end of viewInbox()
```

In other words, when the user cin's 1, The stuff circled in red needs to go away:
[image: what needs to be cleared when user cin's 1]

And then the user needs to be prompted to open another email message in the inbox.

Comment: I'm affraid it can't be done using Standard C++; I think you should think about starting writing graphical apps using some library (Ncurses, GTK+, Qt, WinAPI...)